# Clip on guitar tuner

Tags: guitar

I have been using a clip on guitar tuner for a few years now but I still don't know what the switch at the side is for - it has an option for a flat symbol of a sharp symbol.  Can anyone help?

Comment: picture... make... model...?

Answer (score 3):

Could be many things, but I would guess that this is to change the frequency you tune to.

Standard concert pitch is A=440Hz, but for reasons, you might want to tune sharp or flat from that standard, and those buttons (probably) allow you to do that.

Comment: Practical test - if pressing + makes it say 441, 442, 443... then you're probably right

Comment: These buttons likely allow you to calibrate the tuner itself to a fixed pitch instrument like a piano or pipe organ, so that your guitar will sound in tune with the piano when the guitar is tuned with that device.